# How to create child inside a custom key child?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create child inside child -LoVaDPuBRr4K2JSkc_j , but how?

[image: Structure in my Firebase]

Code :

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
databaseDocument = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Document");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution to add a new property inside your `-LoVaDPuBRr4K2JSkc_j` object would be use that pushed id in your reference like in the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child(uid).child("Document").child("-LoVaDPuBRr4K2JSkc_j");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        dataSnapshot.getRef().child("newProperty").setValue("newValue");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

**Edit:**

Accodring to your comment, if you have more than one key, then you should use a query. The following code will do the trick:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child(uid).child("Document").orderByChild("inspectorName").equalTo("Test");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            ds.getRef().child("newProperty").setValue("newValue");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: what if i have lots of custom child keys? how do i get the values by only writing one child?

Comment: Have you tried my edited solution above, does it work?

Answer (score 2):

To create a child in `-LoVaDPuBRr4K2JSkc_j`, you can do:

```
databaseDocument.child("-LoVaDPuBRr4K2JSkc_j").child("newProperty").setValue("new value");
```

If you want to generate a new child with an auto-generated key, it'd be:

```
databaseDocument.child("-LoVaDPuBRr4K2JSkc_j").push().setValue("new value");
```

Both of these assume that you know the `-LoVaDPuBRr4K2JSkc_j` value in your code. This is required to be a able to add a child, as writing to a location in the database requires that you know the full path to that location.

You'll not want to hardcode this key of course, so there are two common options to have the key:

1. Pass it along your app from the moment when you loaded the data.
2. Use some other value of the node that allows you to perform a query on the database to look up the key.

Comment: what if i have lots of custom child keys? how do i get the values by only writing one child?

Comment: That sounds like case #2 in my answer. If you want to update only one child node in a long list, you can query to find that child node. But that means you must know something else unique to that child. Essentially: how do **you** know what specific child node to update? That's what you must also express in code?

Answer (score 0):

My code and its work :

```
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseProduct = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Document");

        String id = databaseProduct.push().getKey();
        final String productID = databaseProduct.child(id).child("Product").push().getKey();
        final Items items = new Items(productID, dates, nameInspector, locate, product, priceProduct, amount, code);

        databaseProduct.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot getDocumentKey : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    String getDocumentID = getDocumentKey.getKey();
                    String sameDocumentID = getDocumentKey.child("documentID").getValue().toString();

                    if (getDocumentID.contentEquals(sameDocumentID)) {

                        databaseProduct.child(getDocumentID).child("Product").child(productID).setValue(items);
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```